# ngGrid: Do not select row if certain conditions exist in

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a `Select all` checkbox on my ngGrid which works great but I have a situation where when certain conditions exist I do not want a particular row to be selected. So if i click the select all it should select all but the ones where the check fails. This is what I thought would do it:

```
$scope.gridOptions.beforeSelectionChange = function (rowItem, event) {
            angular.forEach(rowItem, function(item) {
                if (item.entity.status == 'Accepted') {
                    item.selected = false;
                } else {
                    item.selected = true;
                }
            });
        }
```

But this does not seem to work. How do I go about achieving this? I tried `afterSelectionChange` too. I see that the data (`selected` property) changes but the selection doesnt change.

The `select all` button is not something I added. This is the one that comes with ngGrid when you enable the checkboxes - the one that is in the header.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);`

See plunkr with example: http://plnkr.co/edit/BffRURwCX7pkNcEo0x6C?p=preview

Edit:

Ok, I see what you need now. You can override the `CheckboxHeaderTemplate` and bind it to a different function.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData',
    showSelectionCheckbox: true,
    checkboxHeaderTemplate: '<input class="ngSelectionHeader" type="checkbox" ng-show="multiSelect" ng-model="allSelected" ng-change="selectAll(allSelected)"/>'
}
```

With selectAll defined as:

```
 $scope.selectAll = function(selectAll) {
    angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(data, index){
      if (!selectAll) {
        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
        return;
      }

      if(data.status != 'Accepted'){
        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made myself clear. I do not have a separate "Select All" button. It is the one that comes when you enable checkboxes - the one in the header.

Comment: Try changing your `item.selected = false;` for `$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);` to mark the item as deselected. To get the index see the functino declaration in my plunkr

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I want only the non accepted ones to be selected when i click that check box (which is ngGrid's version of select all)

Comment: Ok, see the edit now. Let me know if that isn't what you want

Comment: I tried that too but the table never sees the changes on the model. It is almost like the digest cycle doesnt start. I tried to kick off $apply but it complained that the apply cycle was already in progress.

Comment: It has to be something else, also remember that you can't just set the item as `selected = true`. See the plunkr carefully, it is working there in both places

Comment: Sorry, the plunkr I had pasted wasn't updated. Should be fine now

Comment: Intersting. It works in the plunk but doesnt work in my project. Wonder if I have set some property that is causing it not being refreshed.